# Selenium generating error “Element is not interactable” for span sub class

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I continue to get errors about element is not intractable from the following code and website. I have attached the html screenshot and my full code. Hope someone can help me in this. I've tried waiting in anticipation of the button but it does not work. I need to download each of these transcripts into my folder and it is necessary for me to search for them by dates, which is why I am using xpath containing dates

```
 months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 
          'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']

 years = ['1983', '1982', '1981', '1980', '1979', '1978', '1977', '1976', '1975', '1974', 
         '1973', '1972', '1971', '1970', '1969', '1968', '1967', '1966', '1965', '1964', 
         '1963', '1962', '1961', '1960']

driver.get(f'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677')
driver.set_page_load_timeout(15)

for y in years:
    for m in months:
        pdf_links = []
        xpath = "//*[contains(text(), '"+m+"') and contains(text(), '"+y+"')]"
        period = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
        #period = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, xpath)))
        #driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", period)
        period.click()
        driver.quit()
```

[html code of the website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cmX16.jpg)

Comment: I also tried but I get max retry errors

driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", period)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with the below xpath.

Add the below imports.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

And Update the script as below

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(
    executable_path=os.path.join(GenericMethods.get_full_path_to_folder('drivers'), "chromedriver.exe"),
    chrome_options=chrome_options)
months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June',
          'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']

years = ['1983', '1982', '1981', '1980', '1979', '1978', '1977', '1976', '1975', '1974',
         '1973', '1972', '1971', '1970', '1969', '1968', '1967', '1966', '1965', '1964',
         '1963', '1962', '1961', '1960']

driver.get(f'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677')
driver.set_page_load_timeout(15)
pdf_links=[]
search = driver.find_element_by_class_name('list-search.form-control.input-sm')
for y in years:

    for m in months:
        print (m + "-" + y)
        search.clear()
        search.send_keys(y)
        WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(., '" + y + "')]/parent::a")))
        xpath = "//span[contains(., '" + m + "') and contains(., '" + y + "')]/parent::a"
        elinks = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(xpath)
        if len(elinks)>0:
            print(elinks[0].get_attribute('href'))
            pdf_links.append(elinks[0].get_attribute('href'))

driver.quit()
print(pdf_links)
```

Here is the output (trimmed to show only prd_links output due to chars limitation in Stackoverflow)

```
['https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/23077', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/23344/content/pdf/FOMC19830209Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/23084/content/pdf/FOMC19830329Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/23085', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/23086/content/pdf/FOMC19830524Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/23080/content/pdf/FOMC19830623material', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/23081/content/pdf/FOMC19830713Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/23082/content/pdf/FOMC19830823Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/23088', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/23089/content/pdf/FOMC19831004Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/23091/content/pdf/FOMC19831115Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/23079', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/23079', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/23079', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/23060/content/pdf/FOMC19810203Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/23053/content/pdf/FOMC19810331Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/23056', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/23062/content/pdf/19810506MoACC', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/23066', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/23328/content/pdf/FOMC19810707Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/23068', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/23346/content/pdf/FOMC19811006Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/23057/content/pdf/FOMC19811117Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/23341/content/pdf/FOMC19811222Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/23040/content/pdf/FOMC19800109Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/23041/content/pdf/FOMC19800205Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/527292', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/23046/content/pdf/FOMC19800422Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/23048/content/pdf/19800506MoACC', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/23050', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/23347/content/pdf/FOMC19800709Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/23345/content/pdf/FOMC19800812Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/23045/content/pdf/FOMC19800916Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/23051/content/pdf/FOMC19801021Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/23052/content/pdf/FOMC19801118Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/23055/content/pdf/19801205MoACC', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/23027', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/23027', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/23025', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/23029/content/pdf/FOMC19790417Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/23030/content/pdf/FOMC19790522Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/23031', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/23032/content/pdf/FOMC19790711Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/23035/content/pdf/FOMC19790814Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/23036/content/pdf/FOMC19790918Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/23350/content/pdf/FOMC19791005material', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/23348/content/pdf/FOMC19791120Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/23015', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/23354/content/pdf/FOMC19780228Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/23017/content/pdf/19780310MoACC', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/23019/content/pdf/FOMC19780418Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/23020/content/pdf/19780505MoACC', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22498/content/pdf/FOMC19780620Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22499/content/pdf/FOMC19780718Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/23458/content/pdf/FOMC19780815Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/23022', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/23353/content/pdf/FOMC19781017Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/23024/content/pdf/FOMC19781121Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/23351/content/pdf/FOMC19781219Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22488/content/pdf/FOMC19770118Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22489/content/pdf/FOMC19770215Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22490/content/pdf/FOMC19770315Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22491/content/pdf/FOMC19770419Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22492/content/pdf/FOMC19770517Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/23014/content/pdf/FOMC19770621Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/23459/content/pdf/FOMC19770719Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22493/content/pdf/FOMC19770816Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22494/content/pdf/FOMC19770920Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22495/content/pdf/FOMC19771018Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22496/content/pdf/FOMC19771115Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22497/content/pdf/FOMC19771220Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22484/content/pdf/FOMC19760120Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/23460/content/pdf/FOMC19760218Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22485/content/pdf/FOMC19760316Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/23012/content/pdf/FOMC19760420Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/23006/content/pdf/FOMC19760518Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/23007/content/pdf/FOMC19760622Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/23008/content/pdf/FOMC19760720Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/23355/content/pdf/FOMC19760817Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/23013/content/pdf/FOMC19760921Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/23009/content/pdf/FOMC19761019Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/23010/content/pdf/fomcmoa19761108', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22487/content/pdf/FOMC19761221Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22997/content/pdf/FOMC19750121Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22998/content/pdf/FOMC19750219Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22999/content/pdf/FOMC19750318Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22475/content/pdf/FOMC19750415Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22476/content/pdf/FOMC19750520Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22477/content/pdf/FOMC19750617Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22478/content/pdf/FOMC19750715Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22479/content/pdf/FOMC19750819Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22480/content/pdf/FOMC19750916Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22481/content/pdf/FOMC19751021Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22482/content/pdf/FOMC19751118Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22483/content/pdf/FOMC19751216Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/23358/content/pdf/FOMC19740122Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/23003/content/pdf/FOMC19740220Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/23004/content/pdf/FOMC19740319Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/23005/content/pdf/FOMC19740416Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22984/content/pdf/FOMC19740521Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22985/content/pdf/FOMC19740618Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22986', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22993/content/pdf/FOMC19740820Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22994/content/pdf/FOMC19740910Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22995/content/pdf/FOMC19741015Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22996/content/pdf/FOMC19741119Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/23361/content/pdf/FOMC19741217Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22473/content/pdf/FOMC19730116Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22474/content/pdf/FOMC19730213Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22977', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/23362/content/pdf/FOMC19730417Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/23363/content/pdf/FOMC19730515Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22987/content/pdf/FOMC19730619bluebook19730615', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22988/content/pdf/fomcmod19730709', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/23359/content/pdf/FOMC19730821Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22990/content/pdf/FOMC19730918Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22992', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/23001/content/pdf/FOMC19731120bluebook19731116', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/23002/content/pdf/FOMC19731218Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22972/content/pdf/FOMC19720111Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22973', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22974/content/pdf/FOMC19720321Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22975/content/pdf/FOMC19720417Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/23364/content/pdf/FOMC19720523Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22979/content/pdf/FOMC19720620Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22980/content/pdf/FOMC19720718Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22981/content/pdf/FOMC19720815Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22982/content/pdf/FOMC19720919Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22983/content/pdf/FOMC19721017bluebook19721013', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22471/content/pdf/FOMC19721121Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22472/content/pdf/FOMC19721219Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22967/content/pdf/FOMC19710112Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22462/content/pdf/FOMC19710209Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22969/content/pdf/FOMC19710309Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22463/content/pdf/FOMC19710406Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22464/content/pdf/FOMC19710511Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22465/content/pdf/FOMC19710608Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22466/content/pdf/FOMC19710727Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22467/content/pdf/FOMC19710824Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22468/content/pdf/FOMC19710921Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22971/content/pdf/FOMC19711019Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22469/content/pdf/FOMC19711116Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22470/content/pdf/FOMC19711214Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/23368/content/pdf/FOMC19700115Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22961/content/pdf/FOMC19700210Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22962/content/pdf/FOMC19700310Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22963/content/pdf/FOMC19700407Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/23367/content/pdf/FOMC19700505Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22965/content/pdf/FOMC19700623Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22966/content/pdf/FOMC19700721Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/23366/content/pdf/FOMC19700818Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22915/content/pdf/FOMC19700915Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22939/content/pdf/FOMC19701020Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22943/content/pdf/FOMC19701117Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22968/content/pdf/FOMC19701215Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22949/content/pdf/FOMC19690114Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22950/content/pdf/FOMC19690204Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/23370/content/pdf/FOMC19690304Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22951/content/pdf/FOMC19690401Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22953/content/pdf/FOMC19690527Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/23369/content/pdf/FOMC19690624Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22954/content/pdf/FOMC19690715Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22955/content/pdf/FOMC19690812Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22956/content/pdf/FOMC19690909Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22957/content/pdf/FOMC19691007Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22959/content/pdf/FOMC19691125Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22960/content/pdf/FOMC19691216Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22934/content/pdf/FOMC19680109Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22935/content/pdf/FOMC19680206Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/23374/content/pdf/FOMC19680305Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22937/content/pdf/FOMC19680402Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22940/content/pdf/FOMC19680528Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22941/content/pdf/FOMC19680618Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/23372/content/pdf/FOMC19680716Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22942/content/pdf/FOMC19680813Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22945/content/pdf/FOMC19680910Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22946/content/pdf/FOMC19681008Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/23371/content/pdf/FOMC19681126Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22948/content/pdf/FOMC19681217Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22922/content/pdf/FOMC19670110Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/23377/content/pdf/FOMC19670207Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22923/content/pdf/FOMC19670307Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22924/content/pdf/FOMC19670404Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22925/content/pdf/FOMC19670502Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22926/content/pdf/FOMC19670620Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22927/content/pdf/FOMC19670718Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22928/content/pdf/FOMC19670815Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/23375/content/pdf/FOMC19670912Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22929/content/pdf/FOMC19671003Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22931/content/pdf/FOMC19671114Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22933/content/pdf/FOMC19671212Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22907/content/pdf/FOMC19660111Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22908/content/pdf/FOMC19660208Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22909/content/pdf/FOMC19660301Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/23379/content/pdf/FOMC19660412Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22911/content/pdf/FOMC19660510Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22912/content/pdf/FOMC19660607Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/23378', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22916/content/pdf/FOMC19660823Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22917/content/pdf/FOMC19660913Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22918/content/pdf/FOMC19661004Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22919/content/pdf/FOMC19661101Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22921/content/pdf/FOMC19661213Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22892/content/pdf/FOMC19650112Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22893/content/pdf/FOMC19650202Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22894/content/pdf/FOMC19650302Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22896/content/pdf/FOMC19650413Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22897/content/pdf/FOMC19650511Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22898/content/pdf/FOMC19650615Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22899/content/pdf/FOMC19650713Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22900/content/pdf/FOMC19650810Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22901/content/pdf/19650908MinutesCCv', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22903/content/pdf/FOMC19651012Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/23380/content/pdf/FOMC19651102Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22906/content/pdf/FOMC19651214Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22877/content/pdf/FOMC19640107Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/23386/content/pdf/FOMC19640211Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22879/content/pdf/FOMC19640303Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22881/content/pdf/FOMC19640414Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22882/content/pdf/FOMC19640505Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22884/content/pdf/FOMC19640617Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22885/content/pdf/FOMC19640707Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22886/content/pdf/FOMC19640818Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22887/content/pdf/FOMC19640908Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/23384/content/pdf/FOMC19641020Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22889/content/pdf/FOMC19641110Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22891/content/pdf/FOMC19641201Agenda', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22862/content/pdf/19630108Minutesv', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22863/content/pdf/19630212Minutesv', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22864/content/pdf/19630305Minutesv', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/23389/content/pdf/19630416Minutesv', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22866/content/pdf/19630507Minutesv', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22868/content/pdf/19630618Minutesv', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22869/content/pdf/19630709Minutesv', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22872/content/pdf/19630820Minutesv', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/23388/content/pdf/19630910Minutesv', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22873/content/pdf/19631001Minutesv', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22875/content/pdf/19631112Minutesv', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/23387/content/pdf/19631203Minutesv', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/23394/content/pdf/19620109Minutesv', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22848/content/pdf/19620213Minutesv', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22849/content/pdf/19620306Minutesv', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22850/content/pdf/19620417Minutesv', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22851/content/pdf/19620508Minutesv', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/23392/content/pdf/19620619Minutesv', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22854/content/pdf/19620710Minutesv', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22856/content/pdf/19620821Minutesv', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22857/content/pdf/19620911Minutesv', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22858/content/pdf/19621002Minutesv', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/23391/content/pdf/19621113Minutesv', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22860/content/pdf/19621204Minutesv', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22832/content/pdf/19610110Minutesv', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/23397/content/pdf/19610207Minutesv', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22834/content/pdf/19610307Minutesv', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22836/content/pdf/19610418Minutesv', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/23396/content/pdf/19610509Minutesv', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22837/content/pdf/19610606Minutesv', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22839/content/pdf/19610711Minutesv', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/23395/content/pdf/19610801Minutesv', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22841/content/pdf/19610912Minutesv', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22842/content/pdf/19611003Minutesv', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22844/content/pdf/19611114Minutesv', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22845/content/pdf/19611205Minutesv', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22818/content/pdf/19600112Minutesv', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22820/content/pdf/19600209Minutesv', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/23400/content/pdf/19600301Minutesv', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22823/content/pdf/fomchistmin19600412', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/23399/content/pdf/fomchistmin19600503', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22825/content/pdf/fomchistmin19600614', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22821/content/pdf/fomchistmin19600706', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/23398/content/pdf/fomchistmin19600816', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22827/content/pdf/fomchistmin19600913', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22828/content/pdf/fomchistmin19601004', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22830/content/pdf/fomchistmin19601122', 'https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/677/item/22831/content/pdf/fomchistmin19601213']
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206569/discussion-on-answer-by-supputuri-selenium-generating-error-element-is-not-inte).

Comment: @SamuelLiew Thanks for moving the comments into discussion. stackedodds is a new member and because of which SO might have not gave option to open a discussion.

Comment: @SamuelLiew Thank you and thank you to supputuri

I am now trying to download the pdf files from the above code but again I'm facing difficulties with selenium. I am using the following code

`for url in pdf_links:
`page = driver.get(url)
 `       elinks = page.find_elements_by_css_selector("a[href*='.pdf']")
  `      for elink in elinks:
   `         download = driver.find_element_by_link_text(elink)    
    `        download.click()
     `       sleep(1)`

Comment: Please submit a new question for downloading.

Comment: ok I have submitted the question